# How to configure multiple video instances using hls.js and plyr

Tags: video, streaming, plyr, hls.js

I am using plyr (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) and hls.js (https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) for streaming video. The example https://codepen.io/pen?template=oyLKQb works for one video instance. At the moment the document.querySelector only detects the first  instance. How can a I adapt the code to have more than one video instances on the same page?

I have tried to work with ids inside each  instance, e.g. `<video id=player1"></video>`. and called `document.querySelector('player1.video')`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for my problem using `document.querySelectorAll('video')`. If you are interested, you find a codepen here https://codepen.io/MichaGue/pen/oRWVdq